# ckeditor widget template to output a dynamic variable in the link text

Tags: drupal, widget, ckeditor

I have the following code that I need to be able to edit the template of the ckeditor widget. I have learned that templates are immutable. What I want to achieve is to be able to insert a variable in the template. Is it achievable?

```
( function($, Drupal, drupalSettings, CKEDITOR) {  

    CKEDITOR.plugins.add('tabslinks',{
    requires: 'widget',
    lang: 'en',
    icons: 'tabslinks',
    hidpi: true, // %REMOVE_LINE_CORE%

    init: function(editor) {


                editor.ui.addButton('tabslinks', {
                    label: 'Create tabs links',
                    command: 'tabslinks',
                    icon: this.path + 'icons/tabslinks.png'
                });
            editor.addContentsCss(this.path + 'assets/contents.css');
            editor.widgets.add('tabslinks',{

                allowedContent: 'a(!tabslinks), a[!href];',
                requiredContent: 'a', 


        editables: {
            title: {

                selector: '.tabslinks'

                }
                            },

                template: '<a class="tabslinks" href="" >' +
                    'Link should be a variable such as the result of var tabtitle   ' +
                    '</a>',
                button: 'Create tab title and link',
                init: function () {

                  var tabtitle = this.element.getAttribute('data-cke-saved-href');


                  if(tabtitle){
                      this.setData('tabtitle',tabtitle);

                  }

                    },
                upcast: function(element) {

             return element.name == 'a' && element.hasClass('.tabslinks');
            },

                dialog: 'tabslinks',
                data: function() {

             /* Note I can edit the attributes in the following without a problem. The problem is that I cannot manipulate the dom, I have used methhods such as editor CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(html) but that also breaks the widget, I have also tried to use jquery with no luck */
              if(this.data.tabtitle){

                  this.element.setAttribute('data-cke-saved-href','#' + this.data.tabtitle);
                  this.element.setAttribute('data-toggle','tab');



              }


                 }

    } );

    CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'tabslinks', this.path + 'dialogs/tabslinks.js' );
    } 


} );

} )(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings, CKEDITOR);
```

I have tried to use many methods trying to manipulating the dom but this breaks the widget. Any suggestions?